# how to add icon img before a link in css

Tags: css, icons

how do I add an icon img before a link? For example how would I put a icon  phone image before my link.

I have put an icon image through css, but it displays on top of the link text.I only want the position of the icon to be before the text, but when i try to set a position it moves the entire link text with it. I do not want to change position of link text, just the position of the icon to be set before it.

Comment: put both the icon and link in different divs and then give them style display:inline-block; you are done.. :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example from the [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)

I guess that's what you want.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Library</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Applications</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Settings</a>
</div>
```